# jQuery auto complete widget showing previous result in suggestion dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am getting a proper JSON result from "admin/ajax.php" file.
    Example: first I type 1 and I get many records but it does not show in suggestion drop down. But when I type 9, it means in text box 19 then it shows me above records in drop down instead of result from 19.

```
<input type="text" id="invoice_id1" size="20" name="invoice_no" value="" 
    class="ui-widget" onkeyup="find_suggestion(invoice_id1,memberid,this.value);" />

<script>
    function find_suggestion(div_id,memberid,invoice){
        $.post("admin/ajax.php?action=invoice_suggestions", 
            {div_id: div_id,memberid:memberid,invoice:invoice},
            function(data){
                if(data){
                    var tags = data
                    $( "#"+div_id).autocomplete({source: tags});
                }

            }
            , "json"
        );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Since you're using autocomplete set the source to be the remote php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more traditional way to do this would be to use a function as the source which does the ajax call.  I would remove the `onkeyup` completely and just attach this on the ready or load.

I'm not sure why you're passing the `div_id` or where the `memberid` are coming from.  I also am not clear on why you're posting instead of getting.  If you give more details I can assist further.

```
$("#invoice_id1").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.post({
            url:"admin/ajax.php?action=invoice_suggestions",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {div_id: '#invoice_id1',
                   memberid:memberid,
                   invoice:this.value
            },
            success: function(data) { 
                     response( return data; ) 
            }
     }),
     minLength: 1
});
```